# Find the level of the key in a binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
int levelBST(Node node,int key,int level){
  if(node==null)
     return;
  if(node.data==key){
     return level;
  }
  else if(node.data>key){
     return levelBST(node->left,key,level+1);    
  }
  else return levelBST(node-right,key,level+1);
}
```

Is the above code snippet correct or there are some issues. Please help.

Comment: Seems fine. if(node==null)
     return; here return -1, indicating not found.

Comment: It was asked in an interview. The interviewer said that there are some mistakes in the code. Besides the thing you wrote above.

Comment: You don't need to pass level as argument. It should get incremented on each call automatically. eg return levelBST(node->left,key)+1; in first return statement it would be 0;

Comment: ok, i know it's typo, but node-right is node->right, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it that way: (assuming `Node` is a pointer)

```
int levelBST(Node node, int key){
  if(node==null)
     return -1;

  if(node->data < key){
      return levelBST(node->right, key);
  }
  if(node->data > key){
      return levelBST(node->left , key);    
  }
  return 0;
}
```